Opening ProtonMail leads Thunderbird to run
When in broswer (Brave v1.69.162 Chromium: 128.0.6613.120 64-bit) and Ubuntu 24.04 I click on a mailto: link, it asks me if I want to open the ProtonMail App:

but when I click on "Open Proton Mail" button, Thunderbird opens instead.
Why can this happen? Where is hard-coded the wrong path then?
